# Estimation of $\iint_D(x^2+y^2-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+2)dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find an estimation for the integral $$\iint_D(x^2+y^2-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+2)~dx~dy,$$ where $D=[0,2]\times[0,2].$
> Source, Berman

My try:

In polar coordinates, I divided the square into parts $0\le\varphi\le\frac\pi4$ and $\frac\pi4\le\varphi\le\frac\pi2$

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\frac2{\cos\varphi}}(r^2-2r+2)rdrd\varphi+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\frac2{\sin\varphi}}(r^2-2r+2)rdrd\varphi=\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\frac2{\cos\varphi}}(r^3-2r^2+2r)drd\varphi+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\frac2{\sin\varphi}}(r^3-2r^2+2r)drd\varphi\int_0^{\pi/4}\left(\frac4{\cos^4\varphi}-\frac{16}{\cos^3\varphi}+\frac4{\cos^2\varphi}\right)d\varphi+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \left(\frac4{\sin^4\varphi}-\frac{16}{\sin^3\varphi}+\frac4{\sin^2\varphi}\right)d\varphi$$

$$\begin{aligned}\int\frac{dx}{\cos^4 x}&=\int\frac1{\cos^2x}+\int\frac{\sin x dx}{\cos^4x}\sin x=\tan x-\left(\frac13\frac{\sin x}{\cos^3 x}-\frac13\int\frac1{\cos^2 x}\right)\\&=\tan x-\left(-\frac13\frac{\sin x}{\cos^3 x}+\frac13\tan x\right)\\&=\tan x+\frac{\tan^3x}3\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}\int\frac{dx}{\cos^3 x}&=\tan x\frac1{\cos x}+\int\frac{\sin xdx}{\cos^3 x}\\&=\frac{\tan x}{\cos x}+\frac1{2\cos^2 x}\end{aligned}$$

and analogously $$\int\frac{dx}{\sin^4 x}=-\cot x-\frac{\cot^3 x}3\\\int\frac{dx}{\sin^3 x}=-\frac{\cot x}{\sin x}+\frac1{2\sin^2 x}.$$

Now, I ended up with multiple expressions I got lost with and I can't get the estimation from the book :$$4<  I< 8(5-2\sqrt 2).$$ How should I proceed?

Comment: If you are integrating over the square, then your lower limits on the two integrals with respect to $r$ should not start at $0$. They should start at $\csc\theta$ and $\sec\theta$, respectively.

Comment: Based on your work, you have a typo in the question, it should be $~x^2+y^2-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+2~$, instead of $~x^2+y^2-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2~$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to estimate value of $I$ where,

$ I = \displaystyle \iint_D f(x, y) ~dA~$, where

$D: [0, 2] \times [0, 2],~ 
f(x,y) = x^2+y^2-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+2$

I have assumed $f(x, y)$ as in your works. Your question seems to have typo with $+2$ written as $-2$.

$~x^2+y^2-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+2 = (r-1)^2 + 1$

As for the given region, $0 \leq r \leq 2 \sqrt2~$, we can write the range of $f(x, y)$ as $~1 \lt  f(x,y) \lt 2 (5 - 2 \sqrt2)$

Since the area of the square is $4$, we have the answer $~~~~~~~~~~4 \lt I \lt 8 (5 - 2 \sqrt2)$

Comment: I want to apologize. I accidentally copied $[1,2]\times[1,2]$ instead of $[0,2]\times[0,2]$. I'm going to go trough your answer, anyway. Sorry, once again, that you spent your time, it was late when I typed and I fell asleep.

Comment: @Dolphin Then the answer does make sense. But can you fix the integrand? It has $- 2$ instead of $ + 2$.

Comment: I'll fix that and see what I get when I integrate it.

Comment: @Dolphin I modified the answer considering $D: [0, 2] \times [0, 2]$